# How can I create my custom samsung flipfont apk

Tags: android, fonts

like in google play: https://play.google.com/store/search?q=samsung%20flipfont&c=apps&hl=en

I try to create my custom flipfont apk base there apk put my ttf in assets/fonts and write a fonts.xml in assets/xml like this:

```
<sans>
    <file>
        <filename>MyFont.ttf</filename>
        <droidname>DroidSans.ttf</droidname>
    </file>
    <file>
        <filename>MyFont.ttf</filename>
        <droidname>DroidSans-Bold.ttf</droidname>
    </file>
</sans>
```

But when I install my flipfont.apk and select it in samsung display settings, it's say: they aren't compatible with the device.

Does the samsung system check some signature? How can I create my custom flipfont apk. I want to package my font to flipfont.apk and use in samsung device.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a special digital signature involved with FlipFont APK's. Here is a link showing you how to work around this. It is not simple by any means, but, it is effective. Hope this helps.

https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=755472

Answer (score 0):

I've also seen that if you backup the apk app in Samsungs back & restore, then delete it and restore it, it adds the signature that way.